# in the output it is removing the "Django" from both the attributes, what can be the issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Removing from one attribute it is removing the "Django" from another attribute also, what can be the issue

```
class Library:
    def __init__(self,booklist):
        self.permabooklist = booklist
        self.books = booklist

sonipatlibrary = Library(["C++","Django","Flask","Oops"])

print(sonipatlibrary.permabooklist)
print(sonipatlibrary.books)

sonipatlibrary.books.remove("Django")

print(sonipatlibrary.permabooklist)
print(sonipatlibrary.books)
```

Comment: Referenced to same `list`. You need to have clone or copy of the list you can do `list.copy()` or `[...list]`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create separate instance of the lists, right now you are referencing the same list `booklist` in both the properties `permabooklist` and `books`.

You can use `booklist.copy()` method or use `booklist[:]` to copy the list into each properties

```
class Library:
    def __init__(self,booklist):
        self.permabooklist = booklist.copy()
        self.books = booklist.copy()
```

OR

```
class Library:
    def __init__(self,booklist):
        self.permabooklist = booklist[:]
        self.books = booklist[:]
```

You can read about creating [shallow and deep copies](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) in python.